# Common word to be discovered

Tags: riddle, word

I am a four letter word. Part of me, when scrambled, is never straight. Another part of me, read backwards, represents time. A part of me, scrambled, divides people and another part of me is used by many people. Who am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly....

> Care

Part of me, when scrambled, is never straight.

> An ARC cannot be straight

Another part of me, read backwards, represents time.

> An ERA is a representation of time

A part of me, scrambled, divides people

> RACE divides people

and another part of me is used by many people.

> That could be a CAR, most of us use cars

Who am I?

> You are the word 'care'.

Comment: I was thinking this earlier, but it seemed weird that for "a part of me, scrambled, divides people," rot13(n cneg bs zr zrnaf gur jubyr jbeq)

Comment: Yes, and oddly that exact same clue plus the (rather generic) car one were used verbatim in another puzzle the OP gave a month ago. So while I did not downvote this puzzle, I think I understand why others did. No complaints, but I think a little more thought could go into future puzzles to make them more enjoyable. Just my two cents, it's a learning process for everyone.

Comment: Perhaps rot13(enpr) could be rot13(nper).

Comment: The "divides people" part was reused too.

Answer (score 5):

You might be:

> CAMP

I am a four letter word. Part of me, when scrambled, is never straight.

> CA scrambled makes AC = alternating current

Another part of me, read backwards, represents time.

> MP read backwards makes PM

A part of me, scrambled, divides people

> AMP scrambled makes MAP, which divides people into countries

and another part of me is used by many people.

> CAM (camera)